# Kubernetes stuck at 'Starting' with Docker Desktop on Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have issue with version 3.1 of Docker Desktop and on enabling kubernetes its always stuck at Starting
looking at logs in i can see repeating the following log from (AppData/Local/Docker/log.txt):

```html
\"https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/leases/docker-desktop\": net/http: TLS handshake timeout"
[16:15:55.267][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: POST /events 200 \"DockerDesktopGo\" \"\""
[16:16:06.268][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] msg="cannot get lease for master node: Get \"https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/leases/docker-desktop\": net/http: TLS handshake timeout"
[16:16:06.268][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: POST /events 200 \"DockerDesktopGo\" \"\""
```

I have tried deleting the pki folder inside AppData/Local/Docker , but without any success.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a common issue reported [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9324) or [here](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5027), which occurs also on **MacOS**. As per [this comment](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5027#issuecomment-718076014), apart from deleting `pki`, you should also remove `.kube` directory and restart `Docker`:

> I have workarounded as:
>
> ```
> rm -rf ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/pki/
> rm -rf ~/.kube
> ```
>
> And restarting docker

As mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9324#issuecomment-740631055), the respective directory on Windows can be found in:

```
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Docker
```

If none of the above helps, as the last resort solution you may try to completely re-install your **Docker Desktop** as there might be some remnants of the previous installation causing the issue. Compare with [this comment](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5027#issuecomment-776260603).

Comment: Hi, mario i have tried this several times.After doing it sometimes even docker cannot start and i try reinstall until Docker is running but then the kubernetes keeps stuck on Starting state...

Comment: @КалоянНиков, did you manage to find a solution of this issue ?

Comment: I tried several uninstalls/installs, reset to default settings and in the end, it magically started to work. But there are issues when a new update comes sometimes it fails to start K8s again

Comment: Jan-27-2023, this is literally the only thing that worked for me after uninstalling everything several times. I think it is the pki folder delete that was the key.